# How do I write a program to find the number of binary strings of length n containing exactly three 1s, all consecutive

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I've followed a dynamic programming approach here.

dp(i,x) :denotes number of strings of length i with x consecutive 1s in position i + 1 to i + x.

n here is the length of the bit string taken as input from the user

However, I think I'm counting strings that have more than 3 consecutive ones as well maybe?

**EDIT**: Just to clarify

- I am looking for strings with exactly 3 1s. For eg: 111000 is a valid string whereas 1110101111 and 10101000 are not.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int solve(int i,int x,int **arr)
{
    if(i<0) 
        return x==3;
    if(arr[i][x]!=-1)
        return arr[i][x];

    arr[i][x] = solve(i-1,0,arr);
    arr[i][x]+=solve(i-1,x+1,arr);

    return arr[i][x];
}

int main()
{

    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int **arr = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            arr[i][j]=-1;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        arr[i][3] = (1<<(i+1));

    printf("%d",solve(n-1,0,arr));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are (at most) three cases; you could just compute the number of resulting possibilities and add them up.

Comment: What qualifies as a string that has exactly three consecutive ones: Does 11101111 qualify? 11101000? 11101110? In other words, does it mean that, at some position in the string, there are exactly three consecutive ones, and no more, and the rest of the string is irrelevant? Or does it mean thevstring must contain exactly three consecutive ones and no other ones? Or something else?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It means that the string must contain exactly three consecutive ones and no other ones.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it is not very clear at the moment. (hint: use a bullet list for the conditions/constraints)

Comment: If the string must contain exactly three consecutive ones and no other ones, the answer is simple. If n is less than three, there are zero such strings. Otherwise, the ones can start at any position from 0 to n−3, so there are n−2 such strings.

Comment: The condition you're now describing would be better worded as "binary strings of length `n` containing exactly three 1s, all consecutive".

Answer (score 0):

Your DP state `[i][x]` means - number of binary strings of length `i` that have `x` bits in ending, so you're also counting strings like `11110111`.

You need to take into account groups of 3 that are not suffixes, for that you can update dp state as follows: `[i][x][y]` - number of binary strings of length `i` that have `x` bits in ending and a maximum `y` consecutive bits.

Code modification is quite minimal:

```
int solve(int i,int x, int y, int ***arr)
{
    if(y > 3) return 0;
    if(i<0) return y==3;
    if(arr[i][x][y]!=-1) return arr[i][x][y];

    arr[i][x][y] = solve(i-1,0,y,arr);
    arr[i][x][y]+=solve(i-1,x+1,max(x+1,y),arr);

    return arr[i][x][y];
}
```

Comment: This might be very dumb but what is y supposed to be passed as from main()? I'm unable to understand. A working version of main() would really help.

Comment: @AnilVamsi I'm just asking myself if `11110111` shouldn't  be in the accepted set because it has exactly three consecutive 1's in it. Or does exactly three consecutive mean exactly  and at most?

Comment: @nicksheen  I am looking for binary strings that have exactly 3 consecutive 1s in which case 1110111 and 1010100 are invalid whereas 111000 would be valid

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have well understood your question:

The question is not : *"What are all the binary numbers, containing exactly three consecutive ones?"*, but just: *"What's the number of the binary numbers, containing exactly three consecutive ones?"*.

If you are just interested in the number, you might just calculate it by heart:

```
1110xxxxx (total length : N) : amount of such numbers : 2^(N-4) [(N-4) digits with 2 possibilities)]
xx01110xx (total length : N) : amount of such numbers : 2^(N-5)*(N-5)
                                                                [(N-5) digits with 2 possibilities]
                                                                [(N-5) places to put the '01110']
xxxxx0111 (total length : N) : amount of such numbers : 2^(N-4) [(N-4) digits with 2 possibilities]
```

Solution : `2*2^(N-4) + 2^(N-5)*(N-5)`

(I didn't check completely, forgive me if this contains errors)

If you're not sure that you really need to generate all of them, then doing the calculation might actually be a better (and much faster) solution.

Comment: This counts strings such as 11100111 twice.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The OP is not very clear in his phrasing. In that case, one should also check the non-existence of "111" in the xxxx part of the string.

Comment: @wildplasser I am looking for binary strings that have exactly 3 consecutive 1s in which case 1110111 would be invalid

Comment: @AnilVamsi: ... and why would 1110111 be invalid? It does contain three consecutive ones? Eric's comment is correct, saying that my calculation would count it twice. I would think that indeed it should only be counted once, but now you seem to mention that it should not be counted? Why not?

Comment: @Dominique Because it has six ones. I might have framed my question badly. The required string has only one "set?" of 3-consecutive-ones

Comment: @AnilVamsi: and what about the other characters? Can there be one 1, two of them (11), four of them (1111), ...?

Comment: @Dominique No there can't

Comment: @AnilVamsi: but then it's trivial: the only characters, possible in a binary string, are 0 and 1. If you have a binary string of lentgh `N` which should contain exactly three consecutive ones and for the rest nothing but zeroes, then the amount of such strings is simply `N-2` : for N=3 you just have 111, for N=4 you have 0111 and 1110, for N=5 you have 00111, 01110 and 11100, andsoforth.